# Two CMS one domain

Tags: redirect, content-management-system

Till now we had only one CMS and all our website is served through this CMS. Recently due to some limitations of the existing CMS, we had to move a different CMS. So now we are in the process of migrating the existing CMS to new one. Due to the volume of information available on the existing CMS, we are expecting it might take long (more than 8 months) to completely migrate to new CMS. So we have to run both new and old CMS in parallel during the migration process.

My question is what is the best approach to serve pages from both the CMS(s) with least impact. Below are the two options that I think of -

1) Use a generic top level URL (eg- www.example.com/n ) that will redirect to the new CMS and all other will be redirected to existing CMS.
So all URL with this prefix will be redirected to new CMS. www.example.com/n/about.

2) Explicitly define list of top level URL that will redirected to new CMS and all other will be redirected to existing CMS.
for eg- www.example.com/about, www.example.com/news etc will go to new CMS.

Comment: Sai, what did you end up doing?

Comment: at the end had to go with option 1

Answer (score 0):

Since your NewCode/NewCMS will be hosted on the same Domain/Server, perhaps you can think of a thrid option called "subdomain", such that your URL becomes something like:

- news.example.com